# What does the phrase, "Please - allow me!" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-usage

I know that the meaning of this phrase is often context related, but I'm not really sure when or in what situations it can be used. So, I'd appreciate it if you'd just give a context as an example yourself.

(I'm always looking to improve on my English; so, I'd greatly appreciate it if you would point out any grammatical mistakes I've made in describing my question)

Answer (score 2):

This phrase basically means “Please, allow me to help you!”

Mike Brockington has some good examples of situations where this phrase can be used. In general you can use it whenever you see someone who looks like they’re struggling with something and you think you can help solve the problem. The problem could involve manual labor (like struggling to carry something heavy, or trying to maneuver a door while carrying a lot of things, as in Mike’s examples).

You could also say this to someone who is having a mental struggle rather than a physical one. For example, maybe you see a person standing in front of 10 different recycling bins, and they are holding an empty soda can, unsure which bin it should go into. If you are an expert on this collection of recycling bins you could reach out your hand and say “Please, allow me!” - which would tell the person that you want to take their soda can and recycle it for them since you know where it belongs.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to my mind would be if you see someone carrying lots of stuff, and approaching a door - one might jump in front of them and open the door for them.

Similarly, one might see a person about to pick up a heavy load, and say this before helping them - either by sharing the weight or by picking it up yourself.

Comment: I will simply clarify that this is a formal way of speaking. You would not say this to a close friend or family member unless you expected a laugh. But you would *definitely* say it to your girlfriend's mother.